# Server remembering old rewrite rules, even when I remove htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have set up a development server with Ubuntu and LAMP, but for some reason the `.htaccess` is acting strange...

There is a site on there with a set of rules, when I comment them out they still work, and even when I renamed the file to `.htaccesss` it still works! If I delete everything in the file it still works, restarting Apache every time I make a change...

I have tried reinstalling Apache and reinstalled the rewrite module, and it still doesn't work...

Any new rules I add seem to not have any affect at all, so it is reading the rules from somewhere else it seems.

If I cause a syntax error by putting a / in the `.htaccess` file I do get a 500 server error.

Is there a place with cached rules? I've never had this problem before!

**EDIT**: I solved this problem by adding `Options -Multiviews` in my `.htaccess` file

Comment: After renaming .htaccess did you reload or restart apache? Try this and see it helps /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Comment: Yes I even reinstalled it

Comment: Ok I have looked in the log and it seems there is something called a pass through active? its basically removing the php extension but I have no idea where it is coming from...

Comment: I have solved the issue by adding: Options -Multiviews

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth to check whether the caching happens on the client and not server-side. Firefox will cache any 301 (PERMANLTY moved)-redirecteds for a few days. Use 302 (temporary) redirect. To fix "old targets" you can set up an html page redirecting to another domain (e.g. without www) etc. to prevent firefox from using its cache.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a place with cached rules? I've never had this problem before!

(usually) not server-side, but client / browser-side; try to cache-clean your browser as well

---

EDIT 1

suggestion: move out the .htaccess - file from your docroot. when there are still rewrite-rules active, they must be somwhere: either in your docroot or in `<virtualserver>` - config. to disable htaccess for your docroot, add the following to your server-config:

```
<virtualHost>
    ...
    DocumentRoot /some/path
    ...

    <Directory /some/path>

        AllowOverride None

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

- restart apache

If your are sure your dont have any RewriteRule in your Server-Config AND with teh snippet above still get rewrites, i smell fish

Comment: I've cleared it, tried different computers and accessed it by IP instead of a hosts file domain, still working

Comment: strange. what happens when you move the file out of  your docroot?

Comment: and there is a special rewrite-log; i'd turn it on on loglevel 5-9 and see whats happening. after this, i'd `cd $docroot && find ./ -name '.ht*' -ls ` ; maybe some file is  accidentially placed somewhere else in your docroot

Comment: I just noted when I ran usr/sbin/apache2 -V it says: "Server compiled with.... -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork" isn't that supposed to say httpd.conf?

Comment: Ok I have looked in the log and it seems there is something called a pass through active? its basically removing the php extension but I have no idea where it is coming from...

Comment: see my edits above

Answer (score 1):

1. Open browser inspector. (CTRL + SHIFT + I).
2. Switch to network tab
3. Check the Disable Cache checkbox and refresh the site.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Options -Multiviews` in the `.htaccess` file.

Answered by [Adam](https://serverfault.com/users/112086/adam) but wasn't visible so here it is, it works!

Answer (score 0):

This may not help everyone, but in my case I discovered I had an old copy of .htaccess sitting in a parent directory of my site, actually a couple of directories up from my apache htdocs folder and it seems apache traverses up the directory tree and must merge this and my .htaccess in my htdocs folder.   Once I discovered this errant file and removed it the redirect that wouldn't die stopped redirecting.